# How to increase execution time in magento?

Tags: magento-1.7

I want to update price for that I require minimum 15mins to execute the query. I want to increase in WHM.

Comment: have you searched the web on how to increase the execution time for a php script?

Comment: probably cPanel forums will help you much faster

Comment: @Marius I know about php.ini file. ok, I will search in web

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the value configured in php.ini (or from WHM) you have to remove this line from Magentos `.htaccess`:

```
php_value max_execution_time 18000
```

It overrides the maximum execution time. Even Magentos shell scripts read the value from the `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Well that's only true if you're running a webserver that supports .htaccess like Apache. Won't work with NGINX for example.

Comment: OK, but the important point is, "Even Magentos shell scripts read the value from the .htaccess file." which is the thing most people struggle with when dealing with memory limit or execution time: https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/d409dff20e992e97546568974399c456958299f9/shell/abstract.php#L114